# Is there a way to have an integration test having multiple channels without using actual message broker in spring cloud stream?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream

We have used Spring cloud stream with more than one handlers in the same application and we are trying to create an integration test.

Few handlers out of all are as follows:

```
public interface Source1 {

    String OUTPUT = "output_source1";

    /**
     * @return output channel
     */
    @Output(Source1.OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output();
}

public interface Processor1 {
    String INPUT = "input_process1";
    String OUTPUT = "output_process1";

    /**
     * @return input channel
     */
    @Input(Processor1.INPUT)
    MessageChannel input();

    /**
     * @return output channel
     */
    @Output(Processor1.OUTPUT)
    MessageChannel output();
}


public interface Sink1 {
    /**
     * Name of the output channel.
     */
    String INPUT = "input_sink1";

    /**
     * @return input channel
     */
    @Output(Source1.INPUT)
    MessageChannel input();
}

We have channel configuration like follows in application.yml:
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        output_source1:
          destination: source1
          binder: local_rabbit
        input_process1:
          destination: source1
          binder: local_rabbit
        output_process1:
          destination: processed
          binder: local_rabbit
        input_sink1:
          destination: processed
          binder: local_rabbit
```

Here data flows from Source1 -> Processor1 -> Sink1. 
Problem : We need to check the whole flow so in a test case if Source1 produces the data then It should be available in Sink1.. How to test it?

We checked this doc (https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/2.2.0.RELEASE/spring-cloud-stream.html#spring_integration_test_binder) but it says "Test Binder only supports the three bindings provided by the framework (Source, Processor, Sink)"

We have used more than one channel in many functionalities so in integration test those channel linking should be working.
Also, is there a way to have an integration test without using actual message broker?

Answer (score 4):

We're at 3.0.1 version now and the test binder was upgraded to support multiple bindings - https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud-stream/3.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream.html#_testing

Also, just as an fyi, we're moving away from annotation-based programming model and into functional. You can get more info and details from [this post](https://spring.io/blog/2019/11/25/announcing-the-release-of-spring-cloud-stream-horsham-3-0-0-release) (see `Quick highlights` section for more links). In other words you can greatly reduce your code by eliminating `Processor1`, `Sink1`, `Source1`, `EnableBidning`, `StreamListener` etc. . .

Answer (score 0):

One of solutions to organize the code is presented below.

Let's consider we have a class with a supplier, a processor and a consumer. And we have some interface to emit data into the stream by means of `emitData` method.

```java
@Component
public class Handlers {

  private EmitterProcessor<String> sourceGenerator = EmitterProcessor.create();

  public void emitData(String str){
    sourceGenerator.onNext(str);
  }

  @Bean
  public Supplier<Flux<String>> generate() {
    return () -> sourceGenerator;
  }

  @Bean
  public Function<String, String> process() {
    return str -> str.toUpperCase();
  }

  @Bean
  public Consumer<String> sink() {
    return val -> System.out.println(val);
  }
```

For that application we have following fragment of `application.yml` with restriction of bindings to `dev,production` profiles only:

```
spring:
  profiles: dev,production
  cloud:
    stream:
      function:
        definition: generate;process;sink
        bindings:
          generate-out-0: source1
          process-in-0: source1
          process-out-0: processed
          sink-in-0: processed

        bindingServiceProperties:
          defaultBinder: local_rabbit

      binders:
        local_rabbit:
          type: rabbit

  rabbitmq:
    host: localhost
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password: guest
    virtual-host: /
```

And test classes. `AbstractTest` we are using as a common class for all the tests. Let's think we have big application with web/non web parts and with widely used dependency injection which we cannot switch off.

```java
@SpringBootTest(
        classes = App.class,
        webEnvironment= SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT
)
@Import(TestChannelBinderConfiguration.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class AbstractTest {
}
```

`HandlersTest` class we are using for that unit testing only.

```java
@Slf4j
@TestPropertySource(
        properties = {"spring.cloud.function.definition = generate|process"}
)
public class HandlersTest extends AbstractTest {
  @Autowired
  private OutputDestination outputDestination;

  @Autowired
  private Handlers handlers;

  // A way to test a workflow with internal function composition
  // declared through spring.cloud.function.definition
  @Test
  public void testGeneratorAndProcessor() {
      final String testStr = "test"; 
      handlers.emitData(testStr);

      Object eventObj;
      final Message<byte[]> message = outputDestination.receive(1000);

      assertNotNull(message, "processing timeout");
      eventObj = message.getPayload();

      assertEquals(new String((byte[]) eventObj), testStr.toUpperCase());
  }

  // A way to test processor function only with direct
  // access to the function

  @Autowired
  private FunctionCatalog catalog;

  @Test
  public void testProcessor() {
    final String testStr = "test"; 

    final Function<String, String> function = catalog.lookup("process");
    assertNotNull(function, "The function was not found");

    final String result = function.apply(testStr);
    assertEquals(result, testStr.toUpperCase());
  }
}
```

The test `testGeneratorAndProcessor` we can use for partial testing of the workflow with internal transmitting of the data from `generate` to `process`. In that case we have only one output with an index `0` and no inputs. By same way we can collect different combination of the workflow like `process|sink`with one input and no outputs or full workflow `generate|process|sink` with no inputs and no outputs.

When we need to test one specific function only, it is simpler to use `catalog.lookup` to directly get that function.